# Streamlit - How can I know that cache data is used?

Tags: python, caching, streamlit

Part of my code uses `@st.cache`.

I would like to print a message when cached data is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Following code sample and explanation from streamlit doc can be useful to tweak into a value that is only printed first time. Vice versa can be more tricky.

```
import streamlit as st
import time

@st.cache(suppress_st_warning=True)  #  Changed this
def expensive_computation(a, b):
    #  Added this
    st.write("Cache miss: expensive_computation(", a, ",", b, ") ran")
    time.sleep(2)  # This makes the function take 2s to run
    return a * b

a = 2
b = 21
res = expensive_computation(a, b)

st.write("Result:", res)
```

Explanation from Streamlit: *Now when you rerun the app the text "Cache miss" appears on the first run, but not on any subsequent runs. That's because the cached function is only being executed once, and every time after that you're actually hitting the cache.*

Source: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/caching

Comment: Well yes, that's the problem I have. I want to print something when the cached data is used... Thank you for the comment though.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer as well. My idea is to return the answer and a timestamp, and then check if the timestamp has been updated since last time and print something if so, but anything built in would be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my second idea, which is more elegant: use the cache to store a flag that tells us if the cache was updated, and have it default to False otherwise. If it was updated, the flag tells you, otherwise, you know you are using cached data.

```
import streamlit as st
import time

@st.cache(suppress_st_warning=True)
def expensive_computation(a, b):
    st.session_state["cache_updated"] = True
    time.sleep(2)  # This makes the function take 2s to run
    return a * b

while True:
    a = 2
    b = 21
    res = expensive_computation(a, b)
    if st.session_state.get("cache_updated", False):
       print("Res is new data")
    else:
       print("Res is cached data")
    st.session_state["cache_updated"] = False # will be false until function is run again and not cached

    st.write("Result:", res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable using some interal functions, you can (as of version 1.29.0) check whether a given function call is cached ahead of time and dispatch on that information however you please with a function like this. `args` should hold positional placeholders (eg. `None`) for variables which are are `_ignored`.

```
def is_cached(
        func: types.FunctionType,
        args: tuple[Any, ...],
        kwargs: dict[str, Any] = {}
    ) -> tuple[bool, Any]:

    cached_func = func.__dict__['clear'].__self__
    info = cached_func._info
    cache = info.get_function_cache(cached_func._function_key)
    value_key= _make_value_key(
        cache_type=info.cache_type,
        func=info.func,
        func_args=args,
        func_kwargs=kwargs,
        hash_funcs=info.hash_funcs
    )

    try:
        return True, cache.read_result(value_key).value
    except CacheKeyNotFoundError:
        return False, None

@st.cache_data
def test(var):
    return var

cached_p, value = is_cached(test, (1,))
st.write((cached_p, value))
# => (False, None)

test(1)
cached_p, calue = is_cached(test, (1,))
st.write((cached_p, value))
# => (True, 1)
```